# Windows Server 2008: Progress Bar in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-server-2008

Server: Windows 2008 SP 2

Hello, 
whenever I'm navigating to some subdirectory in the Windows Explorer, there is a "Progress Bar" starting up in the input area. It takes minutes everytime to simply navigate into a subdirectory. How can this be turned off?

Comment: BTW, Indexing Service has already been turned off,  but this did not change this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

See here:  [Windows Server 2008 expanding folders is Slow](https://serverfault.com/questions/201045/windows-server-2008-expanding-folders-is-slow)

Also, I have seen UAC cause this issue as well, but don't necessarily recommend turning it off.

Like the link says in one of the answers, try doing a "dir" from a command prompt as well as switching directories, etc. from the cmd prompt to see for sure, but that link should help you to diagnose (be sure and read the comments too).